# RegEx to match some wrapped texts

Tags: regex, text, pcre

Consider following text:

```
aas(  I)f df (as)(dfdsf)(adf).dgdf(sfg).(dfdf) asdfsdf dsfa(asd #54 54 !fa.) sdf
```

I want to retrive text between parenthesis, but adjacent parentheses should be consider a single unit. How can I do that?

For above example desired output is:

- (  I)
- (as)(dfdsf)(adf)
- (sfg).(dfdf)
- (asd #54 54 !fa.)

Comment: `(sfg).(dfdf)` is considered adjacent, even with the `.` between?

Comment: @Wiseguy Yes, It is considered. Just alphabet and numbers disjoint parenthesis

Comment: There is space in the first token `(  I)`. You sure it is valid?

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes, it's valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assumption

- No nesting `()`, and no escaping of `()`
- Parentheses are chained together with the `.` character, or by being right next to each other (no flexible spacing allowed).
- `(a)(b).(c)` is consider a single token (the `.` is optional).

#### Solution

The regex below is to be used with global matching (match all) function.

```
\([^)]*\)(?:\.?\([^)]*\))*
```

Please add the delimiter on your own.

[**DEMO**](http://www.regex101.com/r/uV5qT7)

#### Explanation

Break down of the regex (spacing is insignificant). After and including `#` are comments and not part of the regex.

```
\(             # Literal (
[^)]*          # Match 0 or more characters that are not )
\)             # Literal ). These first 3 lines match an instance of wrapped text
(?:            # Non-capturing group
  \.?          # Optional literal .
  \([^)]*\)    # Match another instance of wrapped text
)*             # The whole group is repeated 0 or more times
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used `\([^)]*\)(?:[^\pL]*?\([^)]*\))*`

Answer (score 1):

try `[^(](\([^()]+([)](^[[:alnum:]]*)?[(][^()]+)*\))[^)]`. capture group 1 is what you want.

this expression assumes that every kind of character apart from parentheses mayy occur in the text between parentheses and it won't match portions with nested parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with: `/(?:\(\w+\)(?:\.(?=\())?)+/g`

- `\(\w+\)` to match a-zA-Z0-9_ inside literal braces
- `(?:\.(?=\())?` to capture a literal `.` only if it's followed by another opening brace
- The whole thing wrapped in `(?:)+` to join adjacent captures together

```
var str = "aas(I)f df (asdfdsf)(adf).dgdf(sfg).(dfdf) asdfsdf dsfa(asdfa) sdf";
str.match(/(?:\(\w+\)(?:\.(?=\())?)+/g);
// -> ["(I)", "(asdfdsf)(adf)", "(sfg).(dfdf)", "(asdfa)"]
```

Comment: Just noticed that your question was for [tag:php].  Shows how much attention I paid, but the regex will still work!

Answer (score -2):

This one should do the trick:

```
\([A-Za-z0-9]+\)
```

Comment: it won't as it doesn't take into account adjacency of text in parentheses.